# Which node forever.js is callling?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, forever

I use forever.js in my server. When I run `forever start index.js`, it runs fine, but when I call `node index.js`, it says:

```
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install nodejs
```

I tried running `which node`, the above message was shown too. I am confused. Has node.js been installed in my server or not?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the package `node` refer to some program that have nothing to do with node.js.
As such, the package `nodejs` is used, and forever seems to be searching for that.

You should search how to point the right executable to forever in the options.

A quick look at the [documentation](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) seems to imply you should call:

```
forever start index.js -c node
```

Or if not recognized

```
forever start index.js -c /path/to/node
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know whether the nodejs is installed or not, because the foreverjs runs fine, but when called, the console says nodejs is not installed

Comment: @OscarYuandinata: What is the result of `which node`, `which nodejs`, and what forever print when you start it fine?

Comment: While I have uninstalled the nodejs, looks like nvm is installed as well. Somehow the foreverjs is calling nodejs in nvm folder, while running `which` results in the message above. The problem is solved now. Thanks anyway :)